# Heroku database push operation

Tags: sql-server, database, git, bash, heroku

To load a database which runs now on the my computer, SQL Server 2012 and Windows, I have installed Git Bash, taps and Heroku.

Now, whenever I wrote the command

```
heroku db:push --app myapp
```

it gives the same error

> Invalid database ur

I think I miss something, I have not declared which database should be pushed to the Heroku.

Can you help me with this problem ? how can I use heroku db:push, are there any other steps like creating something ? Why I get this error ? Maybe you will say that "have you read documentation or have you searched google?", Yes

EDIT: What I have know is

Local database

```
    Server name                                          Heroku database
    Database name                                          application name
    username    | or windows authentication                postgres database
    password    |                                          username and password
                                                           aws address
```

Should I put/load some file/gem into the Git ?

EDIT 2:

I have test this command but it gives other error.

```
    heroku db:push postgres://localdbUSERNAME:localdbpassword@localdbDATABASENAME/localdbSERVERNAME  --app myapp
```

Error

```
   Failed to connect to database:
   Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku db:push does not work with SQL Server, it works with MySQL and/or Postgres. You'll need to switch to running one of these database servers, run your migrations/seeds and then use `heroku db:push` to push your local database to Herokul

Comment: I have opened Mysql database and now it is running on the mysql database. I have  wrote heroku db:push postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname --app myapp, it gives cannot load such file -- pg error. ? how can I fix it ? Should I load something into the myapp git area ?